# How to get output from High Pass filter on this signal?

Tags: filters, signal-analysis, fourier-transform, highpass-filter

I'm trying to solve this exercise:

> Consider a High-Pass filter with a cutoff frequency of $W=2\pi$
>
> Calculate the output signal if the input signal is $x(t)=\displaystyle \frac{\sin(4\pi t)}{\pi t}$

The fourier transform for the input signal is:

$X(\omega)= \left\{ \begin{array}{lcc}
             1 &   \text{if}  & -4\pi \lt \omega \lt 4\pi \\[2ex]
             0 &  \text{otherwis}e \\
             \end{array}
   \right.$

Now, the output signal is :
$Y(\omega)=H(\omega)X(\omega)$

$Y(\omega)= \left\{ \begin{array}{lcc}
             1 &   \text{if}  & 2\pi \le |\omega| \le 4\pi \\[2ex]0 &  \text{otherwise} \\
             \end{array}
   \right.$

I can get here, but the solution to the exercise converts this function with inverse fourier transform, giving the result of $x(t)=2\displaystyle \frac{\sin(\pi t)}{\pi t}\cos(3\pi t)$.

I don't know how did they get to that conclusion, I have tried to search for it, but i don't know how to look for that.

I hope that the question is clear. Sorry if I'm lacking some details, it's my first time asking this type of questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you get as $x(\omega)$ is two $\mathrm{sinc}(\pi t) = \displaystyle\frac{\sin(\pi t)}{\pi t}$ shifted by $+\omega_0$ and $-\omega_0$ in frequency ($\omega_0 = 3 \pi$). By the *frequency shift* property of the FT:

$$ 
\mathcal F\left\{x(t) \cdot e^{i\omega_0 t}\right\} = X\left(e^{j(\omega - \omega_0)}\right)
$$

Then, remember $e^{i\omega t} = \cos(\omega t) + i \cdot \sin(\omega t)$. Therefore:

$$
x(\omega) = \sqcap_{2\pi} (\omega - \omega_0) + \sqcap_{2\pi} (\omega + \omega_0)
$$

Doing inverse:
$$
\begin{align}
x(t) &= \mathcal F^{-1}\left\{x(\omega)\right\} \\
 &=\mathrm{sinc} (\pi t) \cdot \big(\cos(\omega_0 t) + i \cdot \sin(\omega_0 t)\big) +  \mathrm{sinc} (\pi t) \cdot \big(\cos(-\omega_0 t) + i \cdot \sin(-\omega_0 t)\big) \\
&= 2 \cdot \mathrm{sinc} (\pi t)\cdot \cos(\omega_0 t) \\
&= 2 \cdot \frac{\sin(\pi t)}{\pi t}\cdot \cos(3 \pi t)
\end{align}
$$

since $\cos(-x)=\cos(x)$ and $\sin(-x)=-\sin(x)$

Answer (score 1):

So you have to take the inverse Fourier transform of the output of the highpass filter which you have correctly defined. Instead of directly computing the result $y(t)$ by evaluating the inverse Fourier transform integral; $$y(t) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{2\pi < \lvert \omega\rvert <4\pi} {1 e^{j\omega t} d\omega }$$ you can also use the **linearity** property of the Fourier transform to directly write the answer, without explicitly evaluating the integral.

More specifically, you can see by inspection of $Y(\omega)$ that $$ Y(\omega) = Y_{4\pi}(\omega) - Y_{2\pi}(\omega),$$  where $Y_{4\pi}(\omega)$ corresponds to the frequency response of an ideal lowpass filter with cutoff frequency $W_1 = 4\pi$ radians per second, and $Y_{2\pi}(\omega)$ corresponds to the same type of filter with a cutoff frequency $W_2 = 2\pi$ radians per second. Since you already know the inverse Fourier transform of the ideal zero phase lowpass filter with a cutoff frequency $W$ radians per second and a gain of unity as given by: $h_{W}(t)  = \displaystyle \frac{\sin(W t)}{\pi t}$, therefore you conclude;
$$ y(t) = h_{4\pi}(t) - h_{2\pi}(t) = \frac{\sin(4\pi t)}{\pi t} -\frac{\sin(2\pi t)}{\pi t} $$ What remains is trigonometric simplification; (At this point I've to note that from a number of possible trigonometric simplifications (which are all equivalent as a correct answer) I'll choose the one that yields the provided answer, and how do I decide on that is by inspection of the provided answer using educated guess again):

\begin{align}
y(t) &= \frac{1}{\pi t} \big( {\sin(4\pi t) - \sin(2\pi t) } \big)\\
&= \frac{1}{\pi t}\big( {\sin(3\pi t + \pi t) - \sin(3\pi t -\pi t) }\big)\\
&= \frac{1}{\pi t}\bigg( {\sin(3\pi t) \cos(\pi t) + \cos(3\pi t) \sin(\pi t) - \big[ \sin(3\pi t) \cos(\pi t) - \cos(3\pi t) \sin(\pi t)\big]}\bigg)\\
&= \frac{1}{\pi t}\big( {\sin(3\pi t) \cos(\pi t) + \cos(3\pi t) \sin(\pi t) - \sin(3\pi t) \cos(\pi t) + \cos(3\pi t) \sin(\pi t) }\big)\\
& = \frac{1}{\pi t}  {2\cos(3\pi t) \sin(\pi t) }\\
&= 2\frac{\sin(\pi t)}{\pi t}  {2\cos(3\pi t)  }
\end{align}

Note that another perspective in the inspection of $Y(\omega)$ may result in the conlcusion as @oxuf did, and that interpretation can provide a more simpler and elegant procedure of obtaining the same result, I belive.